# Regex expression to match string with specifc char

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm parsing different documents and I want a regex pattern to eliminate any character that is not included in the pattern.
The pattern I used is `'[^0-9^a-z^A-Z^.^,^/^-]'` and I get my output string with `re.sub('[^0-9^a-z^A-Z^.^,^/^-]', ' ', line)`

But if line is `iban: es45 **** **** 1234 5678 9012` the asterisks disappear.
I've tried this pattern `'[^0-9^a-z^A-Z^.^,^/^-^*]'` but then strings like  `16-01-2107` fail.

I want to process strings like these:

```
foo
Foo
BAR: foo 
Bar B.R.
45%
1.000,42
16-01-2107
16/01/2107
es45 **** **** 1234 5678 9012
```

My pattern works with all these strings except the last one.

How I can modify the pattern for this case?

EDIT:
To be more concise, I want get the strings that I have written just above, eliminating the rest of the characters that the file line might contain, such as tabulations, line breaks, empty line, non-ASCII characters, {} or |

Comment: What's the expected output exactly? Also, you mention that you're trying to eliminate any characters not in the pattern, but what exactly is that? Your regex is not correct, so it's hard to determine what you're actually trying to do. I think you're trying to match anything that is not `0-9a-zA-Z.,/-`. If that's the case just use `[^0-9a-zA-Z.,/-]`

Comment: your question seems ambiguous use, bullets to list expected and intended

Comment: Maybe [`[^0-9a-zA-Z.,/*-]`](https://regex101.com/r/4yhNoL/1/) with this [outcome](http://rextester.com/CITLM30581)?

Comment: You're right. My question is not clear. I've edited it. The strings I've written are the output that I need. However, the lines file contains other characters, tabulations, empty lines, /r/n... and I need eliminate it

Comment: @the-fourth-bird it's just what I was looking for. The Regex is so big and so hard. I think I complicate trying expressions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So given a string, you want to eliminate all characters from the string ***except*** these characters: `[0-9a-zA-Z.,/*-]`.

For starters, the regex to match any character except those characters is

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z.,/*-]
```

Using this code will give you an output string having removed all the desired characters:

```
re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z.,/*-]+', '', line)
```

Using your example strings, here is what the output of each one would be:

```
foo
Foo
BARfoo //space and colon removed
BarB.R. //space removed
45 //removed %
1.000,42
16-01-2107
16/01/2107
es45********123456789012  //spaces removed
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but @the-fourth-bird he wrote just what I was looking for. Practically the same as you posted. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly escape the characters, try the following.

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z.,\-\*]+$
```

Comment: This is wrong. In python re inside brackets you don't have to escape these characters, because they have not special meaning inside them.

Comment: im a javascript user, this is just a general regex, agnostic.

Comment: @MegaIng it doesn't mean it's wrong. You can, optionally, escape characters in sets.

Comment: Also, the first regex doesn't fit the requirements.

Comment: The only character that *may* need escaping is `-` – but unfortunately, OP is far from clear to determine whether it is required, or a fluke because of indiscriminately adding `^` to Make It Work ...

Comment: @MegaIng can you please show the correct one, that would be useful?

Comment: @Remario The ^ is missing, but I believe it is a typo.

Comment: Where exactly? are you referring  to

Comment: @Remario In the first regex in your answer there has to be an ^ at the begging to fulfill the wish of the question, like so: `[^0-9a-zA-Z.,\-\*]+`. I believe this is a typo, because on the second regex you added it.

Comment: here are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), the opening square bracket [, and the opening curly brace {, These special characters are often called "metacharacters". Most of them are errors when used alone.

Comment: But *all* of them, except the backslash, loose their magical properties inside a character class definition `[...]`! Only `^` and `-` get added (and then only when in a proper position).